# How to generate a list of all valid URLs served by my site

Tags: 7, uri

Is there a way to generate a list of all valid URLs that a site will resolve, including redirects?

Specifically, all views, nodes, and redirects (the *from* and *to*.)

The list is required for record reasons by a college in another department.

An answer would be especially useful if it didn't require a code change, as it's production site, and a code change would have to go through code review and require a release, but if it's necessary then it's necessary.

Module wise, among many others, xmlsitemap, redirect, path redirect import, pathauto and pathologic are installed. I'm not sure if any of those might be of any use.

As a second question, if there isn't a way of automatically generating all of the URLs in a pleasantly formatted list, then besides manually collecting all of the views URLs and the redirects urls, where else should I be looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a number of website checking tools (aka. robots or spiders) that will crawl a given website and generate a number of reports, including a report of all URLs found on that site by recursively crawling the site from some starting point (crawl foundation page).

Below are links to three such tools that I've used for this purpose:

- WebCheck: http://arthurdejong.org/webcheck/
- Link Sleuth: http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html
- DRKSpider: http://www.drk.com.ar/spider.php

Note that these will only report URLs that are *reachable* from the crawl foundation page. If your site consists of sub-sites that are *not* reachable from each other, you need to set up more than one crawl foundation.